# Difference between .NET Core and Entity Framework Core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Difference between .NET Core and Entity Framework Core? Can we use Entity Framework Core in .NET Core? What are the advantages of having both?

Answer (score 6):

- Entity Framework Core is an object-database mapper (and a successor to Entity Framework).
- .NET Core is a cross-platform software framework developed by Microsoft (and a successor to .NET Framework).

They are two different things, hence uncomparable. The latter is used to develop applications of any kind, the former makes it easy to build data-oriented applications.

Both save you time implementing widely adopted patterns.

And yes, you can use Entity Framework Core on .NET Core.

Answer (score 3):

Entityframework Core is one Orm that you can use on .net core framework. The .net core is the framework, you can do many things on a framework like develop a web site or another application. You can read a bit about frameworks and what they do. Just have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework).

An orm helps to map your data objects. For example you have a database on a server and you need to read and write data on this database; with help of an orm tool you can create a relational map of your database objects and reach them easily.  I suggest you read about a bit about ORM and what they do. you can look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) 
and for details of entityframework core you can have look to official [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/)

Frame work :

> In computer programming, a software framework is an abstraction in which software providing generic functionality can be selectively changed by additional user-written code, thus providing application-specific software. It provides a standard way to build and deploy applications and is a universal, reusable software environment that provides particular functionality as part of a larger software platform to facilitate development of software applications, products and solutions. Software frameworks may include support programs, compilers, code libraries, tool sets, and application programming interfaces (APIs) that bring together all the different components to enable development of a project or system.

ORM :

> Object-relational mapping (ORM, O/RM, and O/R mapping tool) in computer science is a programming technique for converting data between incompatible type systems using object-oriented programming languages. This creates, in effect, a "virtual object database" that can be used from within the programming language. There are both free and commercial packages available that perform object-relational mapping, although some programmers opt to construct their own ORM tools.

Comment: nzrytmn Thank you for providing links as well

Comment: @user215 I see you confused about terms , reading about this terms will help you.